# How to make an image slider with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

How can I make a content slider, like the popular product sliders shown on most websites (Flipkart, Amazon), which scroll left and right on button click, similar to this image:

[image: image slider]

I have only four contents showing, but I want to add some more, and I want it to slide on button click. Sorry, I dont know the exact term for it.

These content values would be dynamic.

```
<div class="dialog">
            <div class="shop_img">
                <img src="../image/shops/1.jpg">
            </div>
            <hr id="hr">
            <div class="shop_name">
                <?php echo $name;?>
            </div>
            <a href="detail.php?add=<?php echo $add_id;?>"><div class="address">
                <span id="1">ADDRESS</span><span id="2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></i></span>
            </div></a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Maybe Helpful : http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called carousel.

You can use a javascript plugin called owl carousel from here http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/ to achieve that effect.

You can use php foreach loop to dynamically generate your carousel items inside carousel container like below:

```
<?php
    foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
        ob_start();
        ?>
        <div class="dialog">
            <div class="shop_img">
                <img src="../image/shops/<?php echo $item->imageName;?>">
            </div>
            <hr id="hr">
            <div class="shop_name">
                <?php echo $item->name;?>
            </div>
            <a href="detail.php?add=<?php echo $item->id;?>"><div class="address">
                <span id="1">ADDRESS</span><span id="2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></i></span>
            </div></a>
        </div>
<?php
        $itemHtml = ob_get_clean();
        print $itemHtml;
    }

?>
```

Comment: even though your answer works i used slick...thank you